# PCManFM: same file size unit for all files

Tags: files, pcmanfm

I am using PCManFM 1.2.5 file manager. In the file list, the file size units change dependent on the file size, for example a big file's size is shown as being 1.5 **GiB**, while a small file's size as 320 **KiB**. I'd prefer to see the same size unit for all files. Is there a way to accomplish this?